# How to input user's name and email ID using IVR system

Tags: voice-recognition, ivr

Design an IVR system for a Restaurant in which customers can book their tables for lunch and/or dinner. Advance booking for 2 or 7 days/as you wish.

After the request from user, respond to him that you will confirm the request within 5 minutes. Check availability and send SMS confirming the same.

i)       How can you take names and email Ids of the customers during the process?

ii)     What can you do for repeat customers? How will you identify the repeat customers?

iii)   If there is request for a team size greater than the table size, what will you do? E.g. request for 10 persons when table sizes are 6, 4 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

ia) I'd bail on taking email addresses. If that's a major goal of the system, I'd get the customer to 1) provide it when they arrive, or 2) provide it in an SMS response to confirm the reservation. But using a keypad or voice for an email address would be very error-prone. Once you have an email associated with a phone number, you shouldn't need to collect it anymore.

ib) Names could come either as an SMS response like above, or you could ask them to spell their name on the keypad, and give options to confirm. ie: Jack would be 5-2-2-5, which probably intersects with only a few other reasonably-common names. If no match, perhaps a human can handle a voice recording.

ii) Seems like the incoming phone number would be the major key here. If you use the SMS response mechanism for getting an email address, you could additionally associate that with reservations, which would allow folks to be recognized from multiple call-ins.

iii) This seems like something the hostess/manager/restaurant should handle and choose whether or not to accommodate during that five minute verification period. You could flag it for the customer and say "This party is larger than our largest table size. Are you willing to be seated at adjacent tables?" Most will say yes, but it could weed out some folks who wouldn't be happy with any accommodation.

Answer (score 1):

i) An email address is extraordinarily difficult to capture with an IVR system. Caller's are not accustomed to spelling out their email addresses, much less doing so in a way that's optimal for speech recognition. You're better off asking your callers to confirm their phone number based off the ANI that the IVR system is sent by the telco carrier for the call. You're going to need that for SMS anyway.

As far as names are concerned, you have two paths here. First, it's possible to build a speech recognition grammar that attempts to listen for the vast majority of the first names and last names used in the U.S. -- assuming the caller says his or her name followed by its spelling. The Census Bureau provides a data set of the top 90% of the names used in the U.S. which would be perfect for this purpose. Second, if the caller's name falls outside such a data set, you can simply record the name and spelling and either fall back to human transcription or use the recording directly as-is in the call flow.

ii) The best way to identify repeat customers would be to reference their ANI against a database that would also have their name already saved, recorded, or transcribed. That alone would save an enormous amount of time and hassle for the caller.

iii) Determining how to fit in a party size greater than the size of available tables seems to be a business logic question the answer for which would vary greatly from restaurant to restaurant. That sort of business logic does not really belong in the IVR code and should be separated out and driven entirely from you backend.